# What is the problem in here? it is not working in chrome

Tags: javascript

```
Window.onscroll = () => {
                    if (Window.innerHeight + Window.scrolly >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
                        document.querySelector('body').style.background = 'green';
                    } else {
                        document.querySelector('body').style.background = 'white';
                    }
                }
```

I am new at coding, learning from an online course. Now I am stuck at it. i don't know what is wrong in here

Comment: "it's not working" is not a useful problem statement ... what does it do? what should it do? Why do you mention chrome? Does it work in other browsers, just not chrome? do you have errors in the console (I mean, you will, but did you check?) did you know that `Window` is not the same as `window` and `scrolly` is not the same as `scrollY`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in the comment you got wrong letter cases: window, scrollY

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');
body.style.height = '200vh'; // without content there's no scroll, so this will produce scroll;
window.onscroll = () => {
  if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    body.style.background = 'green';
  } else {
    body.style.background = 'white';
  }
}
```